# Failed to create control dependencies with tf.control_dependencies()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to understand `tf.control_dependencies()`, and wanted to verify it does create control dependencies. Here is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.get_variable('a', shape = [2, 3])
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape = [2, 3])
c = tf.scalar_mul(2, a)
d = tf.scalar_mul(3, b)

with tf.control_dependencies([d, c]):
  f = d-c

print (f.op.control_inputs)
```

It returned `[]`, which was not what I expected. If I added the control dependencies in the following way

```
f = d-c
f.op._add_control_inputs([c.op, d.op])
print (f.op.control_inputs)
```

It gave back what I expected `[<tf.Operation 'Mul' type=Mul>, <tf.Operation 'Mul_1' type=Mul>]`.

So my question is, does `tf.control_dependencies()` really add control dependencies? Or does `f.op.control_inputs` return all the control inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38556). Just changing `tf.get_variable()` to `tf.Varibble()`.